# Let U, W be subspaces of a vector space V. Suppose U ⊆ W. Prove or disprove: U + W = W

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

So, I know that W + W = W. And it makes sense that there is no counterargument that the claim isn't true.

So, here is my attempt:

Claim: $U + W = W$

Proof:

$$W \subset U + W$$

Let $w \in W$. Then $w = w + 0$, which is a sum of an element from $W$ and an element of $U$. Thus, $w \in W + U$, and hence $W \subset U + W$.

$$U + W \subset W$$

By definition, $U + W = \{u + w ~:~ u \in U \text{ and } w \in W\}$. That is, every element $v \in U + W$ is of the form $v = u + w$, with $u \in U$ and $w \in W$. And since $U \subseteq W$, it follows that $u \in U$ implies $u \in W$. Thus, every element of $U + W$ is a sum of two elements of $W$, and hence $u + w \in W$ since $W$ is a subspace. Thus, $U + W \subset W$.

Comment: Very clear proof!

Comment: this looks good. For the last part, I would change "$U+W$ is  a sum of two elements of $W$" into something like "Every element $x\in U+W$ is of the form $x=u+w$ with $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. As $U\subseteq W$, $u,w\in W$ and thus $u+w\in W$ also since $W$ is a vector space. " The original sentence is incorrect since $U+W$ is not a sum of two elements of $W$ (you could just write every element of $U+W$ is a sum of two elements of $W$)

Comment: Looks good to me.  There doesn't appear to be anything missing.  The only thing I might suggest would be to check that you are matching notations with the person who will read it.  I personally learned to use $e$ to denote the additive identity instead of $o$ or $0$, but that's just small nit-picky stuff.

Comment: I believe you mean "since $W$ is a vector space" in the last paragraph.

Comment: @CurtisW I made the small changes you suggested. What do you think now?

Comment: @user129360 Yes this looks better

Comment: It looks good. Alternatively, you may prove the claim using a sandwich argument:
$$
W=0+W\subseteq U+W \subseteq W+W \subseteq W,
$$
where the last "$\subseteq$" is due to the fact that vector addition is closed in a vector space.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. I would just mention that $U+W$ is the smallest subspace containing $U$ and $W$ so with the hypothesis $U\subset W$ it's clear that $U+W=W$.

Comment: Hi Sami, could you please specify exactly how I should incorporate your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is correct and it's the best proof if we define 
$$U+W:=\{u+w\;|\; (u,w)\in U\times W\}$$
but if we define $U+W$ by the equivalent definition: $U+W$ is the smallest subspace containing $U$ and $W$ then the result is straightforward as I mentioned in my answer.